# Значение слова "устряпаться"

Tags: значения, глаголы

Знает ли кто-нибудь слово *устряпаться*? Я недавно слышала его в контексте, из которого понятно, что оно значит что-то вроде *испачкаться*, но может быть я и ошибаюсь. И заодно интересно узнать, какое у этого глагола несовершенный вид. Неужели *стряпаться*? И в какой части России оно распространено?

Comment: [Здесь](http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=111770) нашла информацию с большим количеством примеров из ЖЖ.

Comment: Это ведь ответ, почему вы пишите его как коменнтарий?

Comment: Я новичок =) Перепишу завтра.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Устряпать**   (  несовершенный вид  **устряпывать**  ) означает:

1. испачкать;
2. перен. покрыть чем-л. в большом количестве, обильно;
3. побить, победить, побороть кого-л., одержать верх над кем-л.
4. Устроить что-л. ловко, успешно (толковый словарь Ефремовой).

Распространено это слово в Сибири, на Урале ( Пермь, Уфа, Свердловская обл., Челябинская обл.), в Алма-Ате, а также в Нижнем Новгороде и ряде других городов.

**Устряпаться** (  несовершенный вид **устряпываться** ):

1. испачкаться;
2. перен. попасть в неприятное, затруднительное положение, "вляпаться";
3. кончить стряпню; много наготовить и устать;
4. прийти в состояние алкогольного, наркотического опьянения.

В последнем значении является частью молодежного жаргона и встречается только в Новосибирске и Омске.

> Информацию нашла на форуме [городские
>   диалекты](http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualtopics.aspx?bid=26), [отдельная
>   тема о слове
>   устряпать](http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=111770). Там же можно найти примеры из ЖЖ, интервью, современной художественной литературы (разумеется,все написано жителями вышеперечисленных областей).

Answer (score -1):

Это также может значить "напиться".

Comment: Повтор. Это значение есть в ответе Umari — прийти в состояние алкогольного, наркотического опьянения.